# How to write regex for sentence start with questionmark using java

Tags: java, regex

Below is my String contains

```
The course are:
? This is sample php program
? This is sample java program
```

How to write regex for removing ? and end of the sentence add pullstop(.)

Required output:

```
The course are:
This is sample php program.
This is sample java program.
```

How to do this please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far ??

Comment: You don't really need a regex for that.

Comment: I am using this regex \\s*([\\d\\w]\\)|[\\d\\w]\\.|?)\\s* but its giving error.

Comment: Why has a full stop appeared at the end of one of the sentences?

Comment: My requirement is to if the sentence is stats with ? i need to remove (?) and add full stop to at the end of sentence.

Comment: OK, then why did a full stop *not* appear at the end of the last of your example sentences?

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be replaced in single `String#replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` call:

```
String repl = s.replaceAll("\\?\\s*(.*?)(?=\\n|$)", "$1.");
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/M1bJwB

**Update:** To replace `?` or bullet:

```
String repl = s.replaceAll("[?•]\\s*(.*?)(?=\\n|$)", "$1.");
```

Comment: thanks its working. also we have text contains bullets also    • This is sample php program • This is linux program book how to do this please suggest me.

Comment: Do you want to replace bullet also with dot at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Why regex for this? You don't really need a regex for this. You can try some thing like this

```
   String str = "? This is sample php program";
    if(str.startsWith("?")){
        String newStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("?")+1, str.length()).trim() + ".";
        System.out.println(newStr);  
    } else{
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: What if String doesn't start with '?' then also it will append full stop. Also if String contains "How are you? i am fine" then the o/p will be "i am fine".

Comment: @Ruchira OP said My requirement is to if the sentence is stats with ? i need to remove (?) and add full stop to at the end of sentence. But in your case each time it is appending "." so else is not needed

Comment: @MayurB see this `Required output:  The course are:
This is sample php program.
This is sample java program`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `regex`:

```
String str = "? This is sample php program";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\? ");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find())
{   
    str = m.replaceFirst("");
    str = str+".";
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: what happens for this String `"? How are you? i am fine"` it will replace all `?`

Comment: yes it will remove ? and add full stop to every the end of sentence.

Comment: @Ruchira: Thanks for suggestion, Modified the Answer.